# How to dynamically assign a value to a class property in PHP?

Tags: php, reflection, properties, variable-assignment, dynamic

I would like to assign a value in a class property dynamically (that is referring to it using a variable).

```
#Something like: 
setPropValue($obj, $propName, $value);
```

Comment: Dup of [Can you create instance properties dynamically in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/829823/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$obj->$propName = $value;
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to do this for [static members](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php), you can use variable variables:

```
class Foo
{
    public static $foo = 'bar';
}

// regular way to get the public static class member
echo Foo::$foo; // bar

// assigning member name to variable
$varvar = 'foo';
// calling it as a variable variable
echo Foo::$$varvar; // bar

// same for changing it
Foo::$$varvar = 'foo';
echo Foo::$$varvar; // foo
```

Comment: +1 This is probably the first time variable variables didn't hurt my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
$myClass = new stdClass();
$myProp = 'foo';
$myClass->$myProp = 'bar';
echo $myClass->foo; // bar
echo $myClass->$myProp; // bar
```