# classes assigning variables automatically

Tags: php, oop

I'm making a class and I want to be able to automatically assign variables being posted from an ajax request.

```
function assign_vars() {
    foreach($_POST as $index => $value) {
        if($index == 'car_year') {
            $this->car_year = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

This function would be very handy is their a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: Populating an object using `$_POST`?!

Comment: How else would I populate an object?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the Ajax bit earlier. My bad :)

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/7285971/212218

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try with:

```
function assign_vars() {
    foreach($_POST as $index => $value) {
        $this->$index = $value;
    }
}
```

However the way you go is looking like not thought out solution.

Comment: If `$_POST` contains garbage and it isn't validated or cleaned out, it'll all be added to the object. Not very clean...

Comment: @BoltClock sure thing - but whole idea is not very clean.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following setup:

```
class ClassName
{
  /* Init with default values. */
  protected $_vars = array(
      'car_year' => null
    , ...
  );

  public function assign_vars( $array )
  {
    $this->_vars =
      array_merge($this->_vars, array_intersect_key($array, $this->_vars));
  }
}

$obj = new ClassName();
$obj->assign_vars($_POST);
```

In `assign_vars()`, `array_merge()` will overwrite values in `$_vars`, but only if they are already present (thanks to `array_intersect_key()`).

Comment: Yes that probably is a better option actually.