# how to create a variable in subclass in PHP5

Tags: php, oop, class

i need create a variable with parent subclass.
Example:

**Parent Class**

```
<?php
class parentClass
{
    function __construct()
    {

        $subClass = new subClass();
        $subClass->newVariable = true;

        call_user_func_array( array( $subClass , 'now' ) , array() );

    }
}
?>
```

**SubClass**

```
<?php
class subClass extends parentClass
{
    public function now()
    {
        if( $this->newVariable )
        {
            echo "Feel Good!!!";
        }else{
            echo "Feel Bad!!";
        }
        echo false;
    }
}
?>
```

**Execute parentClass**

```
<?php
$parentClass = new parentClass();
?>
```

**Currently**

> Notice: Undefined property: subClass::$newVariable in subclass.php on
>   line 6

**I really need this:**

> Feel Good!!!

**Solution:**

```
<?php
class parentClass
{
    public $newVariable = false;

    function __construct()
    {

        $subClass = new subClass();
        $subClass->newVariable = true;

        call_user_func_array( array( $subClass , 'now' ) , array() );

    }
}
?>

<?php
class subClass extends parentClass
{
    public function now()
    {
        if( $this->newVariable )
        {
            echo "Feel Good!!!";
        }else{
            echo "Feel Bad!!";
        }
        echo false;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `var $newVariable` in subclass ?

Comment: @eicto, i need CREATE A NEW VARIABLE. See the code... Thanks!

Comment: i see the code now, it looks infinite loop, isn't it ?

Comment: @eicto, there is a loop, only a system of plugins...

Comment: Why `call_user_func_array` instead of just calling `$subClass->now();` on the parent class?

Comment: @OlafErlandsen  `new subClass();` will run _construct again and again, what you trying to do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to declare the property in the subclass:

```
<?php
class subClass extends parentClass
{
    public $newVariable;

    public function now()
    {
        if( $this->newVariable )
        {
            echo "Feel Good!!!";
        }else{
            echo "Feel Bad!!";
        }
        echo false;
    }
}
?>
```

**EDIT**

It's either that, or using [magic methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/829898/825789), which is not very elegant, and can make your code hard to debug.