# php set object properties like array_fill_keys($keys, '') does for array

Tags: php, object, properties

I would like a PHP method that lets me set an object's properties like:

`array_fill_keys($keys, '');`

does for an array's indexes

Comment: If it is a custom built object then i fear you will have to write that method yourself

Comment: @Hanky Panky the thing is that I don't know what the values of $keys will be, and the values of the attributes may be set later. is there a way to set an object's property w/o a value?

Answer (score 1):

This might do the job:

```
// Same value for al properties, uses array values only
function object_fill_properties($properties, $value) {
    foreach ($properties as $property) {
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
            $this->$property = $value;
        }
    }
}

// Different values for each property, uses key-value array
function object_fill_properties_kv($properties) {
    foreach ($properties as $property => $value) {
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
            $this->$property = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, this works for existing properties. If on the other hand you are looking to add properties to an object at runtime, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829823/can-you-create-instance-properties-dynamically-in-php) instead.