# How to set class variables dynamically?

Tags: php

Consider the following code:

```
class Project
{
    public $ProjectID;
}    
class Work
{
    public $WorkID;
}    

public function insert($pData, $tableName)
{
//generate insert here
    $pData->{$tableName . 'ID'} = $result->getId();
}

$p = new Project();
$w = new Work();
insert($w, 'Work');
insert($p, 'Project');

echo $p . ' -- ' . $w;
```

Now how would I go about setting the variable in a **dynamic** way? I'm building a data layer. The `$pData->{$tableName . 'ID'}` doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Which variable would that be?

Comment: For `$w` it would be `$w.WorkID = 7` and for `$p` it would be `$p.ProjectID = 7`.

Comment: I don't think it is clear what you mean by "dynamic" nor where / why you came up with this function setToSeven, nor what is your problem that you need solving with something "dynamic".

Comment: I would be more inclined to use [interfaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) and standardize the name of the property... That way I could have `setToSeven()` just operate on $object->id instead of having a varying property name.

Comment: missing from the question is what is expected from the above code, and the actual result. I suspect that the actual problem here is in the echo statement. Try `print_r($p)` instead.

Comment: Well I'm building a data layer and I made a simpeler question that the real complex question I actually have :P

Comment: OP wants to create properties dynamically at runtime (ala reflection). Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829823/can-you-create-instance-properties-dynamically-in-php

Comment: Would this help here?  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set

Comment: Variables do not need to be created at runtime. Only set dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to dynamically call setters?

```
$y = new stdClass();
$y->prop1 = "something";

$targetProperty = "prop1";
$y->$targetProperty = "something else";
echo $y->prop1;

//Echos "something else"
```

That what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

This is what you're looking for:

```
public function set_to_seven($p_data, $name)
{
    $name = $name . 'ID';
    $p_data->$name = 7;
}
```

[image]

The property name can be a variable. Just like functions:

```
$p = 'print_r';
$p('StackOverflow');
```

For future reference: if you need this statically, you're looking for variable variables,

```
public function set_to_seven($p_data, $name)
{
    $name = $name . 'ID';
    $p_data::$$name = 7;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set public properties by accessing them just like any other definition in the class.

```
$p = new Project();
$p->ProjectID = 5;
echo $p->ProjectID; // prints 5
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I need to set properties dynamically. So I don't know the type of the object and I would like a generic function that sets the key. I'm building a object-relational mapper :)

Comment: Ah, in that case, this question is a duplicate. See my comment on your question.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
class Project {
    public $ProjectID;
}

function setToSeven($pData, $name) {
    $pData->{$name . "ID"} = 7;
}

$p = new Project();
setToSeven($p, 'Project');

echo $p->ProjectID;
```

You just need to echo the variable or set up a toString function on the class to echo the class. To String works like this

```
class Project {
    public $ProjectID;
    public function __toString(){
        return (string)$this->ProjectID;
    }
}

function setToSeven($pData, $name) {
    $pData->{$name . "ID"} = 7;
}

$p = new Project();
setToSeven($p, 'Project');

echo $p;
```