# Using a class in a class

Tags: php, object, twitter, rss

I'm currently receiving this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

Please Note:

- I'm new to php.
- All I have basically done is merge
  http://phpir.com/part-of-speech-tagging and
  http://tappetyclick.com/blog/2013/06/25/twitter-xml-feeds-are-back
- any help would be greatly appreciated.
- my overall goal is to be able to collect all twitter search results and classify each word by its world class (part of speech)

anyway here is my code:

```
<?

//WORDCLASS

class PosTagger {
        private $dict; 

        public function __construct($lexicon) {
                $fh = fopen($lexicon, 'r');
                while($line = fgets($fh)) {
                        $tags = explode(' ', $line);
                        $this->dict[strtolower(array_shift($tags))] = $tags;
                }
                fclose($fh);
        }

        public function tag($text) {
                preg_match_all("/[\w\d\.]+/", $text, $matches);
                $nouns = array('NN', 'NNS');

                $return = array();
                $i = 0;
                foreach($matches[0] as $token) {
                        // default to a common noun
                        $return[$i] = array('token' => $token, 'tag' => 'NN');  

                        // remove trailing full stops
                        if(substr($token, -1) == '.') {
                                $token = preg_replace('/\.+$/', '', $token);
                        }

                        // get from dict if set
                        if(isset($this->dict[strtolower($token)])) {
                                $return[$i]['tag'] = $this->dict[strtolower($token)][0];
                        }       

                        // Converts verbs after 'the' to nouns
                        if($i > 0) {
                                if($return[$i - 1]['tag'] == 'DT' && 
                                        in_array($return[$i]['tag'], 
                                                        array('VBD', 'VBP', 'VB'))) {
                                        $return[$i]['tag'] = 'NN';
                                }
                        }

                        // Convert noun to number if . appears
                        if($return[$i]['tag'][0] == 'N' && strpos($token, '.') !== false) {
                                $return[$i]['tag'] = 'CD';
                        }

                        // Convert noun to past particile if ends with 'ed'
                        if($return[$i]['tag'][0] == 'N' && substr($token, -2) == 'ed') {
                                $return[$i]['tag'] = 'VBN';
                        }

                        // Anything that ends 'ly' is an adverb
                        if(substr($token, -2) == 'ly') {
                                $return[$i]['tag'] = 'RB';
                        }

                        // Common noun to adjective if it ends with al
                        if(in_array($return[$i]['tag'], $nouns) 
                                                && substr($token, -2) == 'al') {
                                $return[$i]['tag'] = 'JJ';
                        }

                        // Noun to verb if the word before is 'would'
                        if($i > 0) {
                                if($return[$i]['tag'] == 'NN' 
                                        && strtolower($return[$i-1]['token']) == 'would') {
                                        $return[$i]['tag'] = 'VB';
                                }
                        }

                        // Convert noun to plural if it ends with an s
                        if($return[$i]['tag'] == 'NN' && substr($token, -1) == 's') {
                                $return[$i]['tag'] = 'NNS';
                        }

                        // Convert common noun to gerund
                        if(in_array($return[$i]['tag'], $nouns) 
                                        && substr($token, -3) == 'ing') {
                                $return[$i]['tag'] = 'VBG';
                        }

                        // If we get noun noun, and the second can be a verb, convert to verb
                        if($i > 0) {
                                if(in_array($return[$i]['tag'], $nouns) 
                                                && in_array($return[$i-1]['tag'], $nouns) 
                                                && isset($this->dict[strtolower($token)])) {
                                        if(in_array('VBN', $this->dict[strtolower($token)])) {
                                                $return[$i]['tag'] = 'VBN';
                                        } else if(in_array('VBZ', 
                                                        $this->dict[strtolower($token)])) {
                                                $return[$i]['tag'] = 'VBZ';
                                        }
                                }
                        }

                        $i++;
                }

                return $return;
        }
}
?>




<?php


//TWITTER

// Include the twitter oauth library for PHP (I put it in a subdirectory
require_once("lib/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php");

// Init
define("CONSUMER_KEY", "mykeyhere");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "mykeyhere");
define("OAUTH_TOKEN", "mykeyhere");
define("OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET", "mykeyhere");

$q='search term';

// Get an authorised connection to twitter
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET);
$content = $connection->get("search/tweets.json?q=".$q."&result_type=recent");

// Send the xml header
header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");
$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$xml ="";
$xml.= '<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?-->'.PHP_EOL;
$xml.= '<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">'.PHP_EOL;
$xml.= '  <channel>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml.= '<title>'.$q.'</title>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml.= '    <description>Search results</description>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml.= '<link>'.$url.'</link>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml.= '    <atom:link href="'.$url.'" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml">'.PHP_EOL;

// Get the status
foreach ($content->statuses as $status) {
    //wordclass 


    $statustext = $status->text;

$tagger = new PosTagger('lexicon.txt');
$tags = $tagger->tag($statustext);

  // Build the tweet url as we don't get this in the status object
  $url = 'http://twitter.com/'.$status->user->screen_name.'/status/'.$status->id_str;
  $date = explode(' ', $status->created_at);
  $xml.= '    <item>'.PHP_EOL;
  $xml.= '<title>'.$status->text.'</title>'.PHP_EOL;
  $xml.= '      <description>'.$tags->text.'</description>'.PHP_EOL;
  $xml.= '<link>'.$url.'</link>'.PHP_EOL;
  $xml.= '      <guid ispermalink="true">'.$url.'</guid>'.PHP_EOL;
  // Format the date since the twitter format doesn't work for rss
  $xml.= '      <pubdate>'.$date[0].', '.$date[2].' '.$date[1].' '.$date[5].' '.$date[3].' '.$date[4].'</pubdate>'.PHP_EOL;
  // Get the attached media 
  /*
  if ($status->entities) {
    if (is_array($status->entities->media)) {
      foreach ($status->entities->media as $media) {
        switch ($media->type) {
          //Currently only photo's supported but I suspected with vine video will be along soon
          case 'photo':
            $enc_type = 'image/jpeg';
            break;
        }
        if (!empty($enc_type)) {
          // We need the file size for the media so try to get this from the headers
          $headers = get_headers($media->media_url);
          $size = $headers['Content-Length'];
          if (empty($size)) {
            foreach ($headers as $header) {
              $h = explode(':', $header);
              if ($h[0] == 'Content-Length') {
                $size = trim($h[1]);
                break; // Found what we need, stop looping
              }
            }
          }
          if (empty($size)) {
            $size = 1; //This is basically a hack to make the rss validate
          }
          $xml.= '      <enclosure length="'.$size.'" type="'.$enc_type.'" url="'.$media->media_url.'">'.PHP_EOL;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  $xml.= '    </enclosure></item>'.PHP_EOL;*/
  $xml.= '    </item>'.PHP_EOL;
}
$xml.= '  </atom:link></channel>'.PHP_EOL;
$xml.= '</rss>'.PHP_EOL;

// Return the xml for the rss
print $xml;
?>
```

the above code returns the following error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /var/www/test/Twitter/index.php

for this line

```
$tags = new PosTagger('lexicon.txt')->tag($status->text);
```

Comment: Try to split error line `$tags = new PosTagger('lexicon.txt')->tag($status->text);` in two lines. Not all php versions allow instant class resolving.

Comment: thanks I have broken the code into two lines. It now reads `$statustext = $status->text;
 
 $tagger = new PosTagger('lexicon.txt');
 $tags = $tagger->tag($statustext);`
However that gives the following error Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: does it work as expected ?

Comment: no it gives the error that is mentioned above

Comment: what ->tag() supposed to be in your case? Is it an attribute of your class PosTagger?

Comment: @SawsanAlKhdair yeah it is supposed to be

Comment: but you don't deal with it as attribute. It's a function in your case so you should have in your class a function with name: Public Function tag($param) {} and it should return what do you expect to set in $tags

Comment: Or you can use dynamic attributes and magic functions check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829823/can-you-create-instance-properties-dynamically-in-php it could help you