# php declare public variable inside function

Tags: php

I want to declare a variable inside a class with an unknown name

```
class Example {
    function newVar($name, $value) {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
}
```

And I want to use it that way

```
$c = new Example();
$c->newVar('MyVariableName', "This is my Value");
echo($c->MyVariableName);
```

The Important thing is, that I do not know the name of the variable. So I cannot put a `public $MyVariable` inside the class.

Is that in anyway possible? and if yes, can i do this with different scopes (`private`, `protected`, `public`) ?

Comment: The property is automatically public and you can't define another visibility

Comment: Doesn't the code work? For me it echoes `This is my Value`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you create instance properties dynamically in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829823/can-you-create-instance-properties-dynamically-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U should use `magic methods` `__get` and `__set` (example without checking):

```
class Example { 
   private $data = [];

   function newVar($name, $value) {
      $this->data[$name] = $value;
   }

   public function __get($property) {
        return $this->data[$property];
   }

   public function __set($property, $value) {
        $this->data[$property] = $value;
   }       
 }


$c = new Example();
$c->newVar('MyVariableName', "This is my Value");
echo($c->MyVariableName); 
// This is my Value

$c->MyVariableName = "New value";
echo($c->MyVariableName);
// New value
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: There is no need for the `newVar()` method, `$c->MyVariableName = "New value";` would suffice for both instantiation and reassignment.

Comment: I was just clarifying for the OP. The current example makes it seem like you have to first use the `newVar()` method to instantiate the "property"

Answer (score 1):

If i am understanding this correctly you can tweak a little bit by using key value array

```
class Example {
    private $temp;

    function __construct(){
       $this->temp = array();
    }
    function newVar($name, $value) {
        $this->temp[$name] = $value;
    }
    function getVar($name){
        return $this->temp[$name];
    }
}
$c = new Example();
$c->newVar('MyVariableName', "This is my Value");
echo($c->getVar('MyVariableName'));
```

Instead of using private you can use protected as well.

Comment: This does exactly the same as OP already has, just more code.

Comment: but as an object it will be always public but now you can have different permission type on the variable and functions

Comment: @voodoo417 I like his method better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for magic calling. In PHP you can use the `__call()` function to do stuff like that. Have a look here: http://www.garfieldtech.com/blog/magical-php-call

Off the top of my head, something like

```
function __call($vari, $args){
    if(isset($this->$vari){
        $return = $this->$vari;
    }else{
        $return = "Nothing set with that name";
    }
}
```

This will also work for private, protected and public. Can also use it to call methods as required in a class

Comment: the `__call` magic method is used to call dynamic methods, not to set properties. Please have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php