# How to make a class and dynamically create variables for it

Tags: php, class

**I just found my out that my post is duplicate of another. Its because I was lacking keywords to search this. I am sorry. Here is the answer of my question. I have never thought getter and setter methods.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/829898/1932414**

How can I make a class and give class some variables to populate and process them in class?

example :

here is my class code :

```
class Classname{
    public function save(){
      //get the dynamically given vars and process them
    }
}


$class = new Classname();
$class->color = 'red';
$class->anothercolor = 'blue';
$class->muchcolor = 'blue';
$class->save();
```

and in the save function I want to make process of given variables. How can I be able to get the variables?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply access dynamic vars with `$this`

```
    public function save(){
          foreach($this as $prop => $val ){

              //make your action 
              echo $prop . '-'.  $val;
          }
    }
```

Comment: oh! this is much closer! but my class have its own default variables as well! Can I only get the after generated variables ?

Comment: just working with this)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Classname{
    public function save(){
        $color = $this->color;
        $anothercolor = $this->anothercolor;
        $muchcolor = $this->muchcolor;
        //do what you need to do
    }
}


$class = new Classname();
$class->color = 'red';
$class->anothercolor = 'blue';
$class->muchcolor = 'blue';
$class->save();
```

or

```
class Classname{
    public function save(){
        $colors = $this->colors;
        //do what you need to do
    }
}


$class = new Classname();
$class->colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'];
$class->save();
```

Comment: the problem is color, anothercolor, muchcolor are dynamic. there might be

$class->flowers = 'rose';
$class->anotherflow = 'rose2';

Comment: look at my edited post, you maybe need something like this ?